# Harmonic Analysis on the Affine Group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups

In my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083528/harmonic-analysis-on-the-real-special-linear-group), I asked about harmonic analysis on the group $\operatorname{SL}(3, \mathbb{R})$. The representation theory of this group appears to be quite complicated, so I am now looking at another group that is of interest in my application: the affine group $\operatorname{Aff}(2, \mathbb{R})$ consisting of matrices
\begin{equation}
  A = (g, t) =
 \begin{bmatrix}
   g_{11} & g_{12} & t_1 \\
   g_{21} & g_{22} & t_2 \\
   0 & 0 & 1
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $g \in \operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{R})$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}^2$. If it simplifies things, I would also be interested in the restriction to $\operatorname{GL}^+(2, \mathbb{R})$ of $2 \times 2$ real matrices with strictly positive determinant (unlike $\operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, this group has only 1 connected component).

I would like to build an algorithm that performs the Fourier transform on this group, which is defined as 
$$
\hat{f}(\lambda) = \int_G f(g) U^\lambda(g^{-1}) d\mu(g)
$$
where $U^{\lambda}$ is an irreducible unitary representation of $\operatorname{Aff}(2, \mathbb{R})$, and $\mu$ is a left-invariant Haar measure on this group (which is not unimodular).

Since we can only work with finitely sampled functions $f$, the way to go will be to assume that $f$ is "band limited", i.e. it is a linear combination of a finite number of matrix elements of irreducible representations. By increasing the number of matrix coefficients (the "resolution" of the algorithm), we can transform an increasingly rich class of functions.

**Questions**

As in my previous question, I'd like to know:

1. Which IURs do I need in order to decompose a function in $L^2(G)$? I'm not set on this particular function space, so if another one is easier feel free to modify the question. I think this question amounts to finding a Plancherel theorem for this group.
2. Are there any explicit formulas known for the matrix elements of the relevant IURs? What about the basis functions of irreducible representation spaces in $L^2(G)$? In both cases, integral representations are fine.
3. Is anything known about the asymptotics of these functions? This is important because the IURs of $\operatorname{Aff}(2, \mathbb{R})$ are infinite-dimensional matrices, so an algorithm will have to choose some cutoff. If functions $U^\lambda_{mn}$ do not decay sufficiently fast (or at all) with $m,n$, that may be a showstopper.

**Strategy**

In response to my previous question, the user named *guest* mentioned that to deal with semidirect product groups (such as $\operatorname{Aff}(2,\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}^2 \rtimes \operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{R})$), I should look at the concept of a system of imprimitivity. I have read a little bit on this topic, but do not yet understand how to apply it exactly. Intuitively I would think that Fourier analysis on the affine group should somehow "decompose" into Fourier analysis on its two factors, but I don't know if that is true or how to make this precise. Some guidance on how the system of imprimitivity concept helps to understand the representation theory of a semidirect product group would be very useful.

Provided that we can indeed understand the representation theory of $\operatorname{Aff}(2, \mathbb{R})$ by understanding the representation theory of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and that of $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{R})$ and then assembling them, the main problem is then to understand $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{R})$. A lot is known concretely about the representation theory of $\operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb{R})$, but I could not find much on $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{R})$. I think that $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{R}) = \operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb{R}) \times \mathbb{R}^*$, so maybe there is an easy way to extend the representation theory of $\operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb{R})$ to $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{R})$?

I did find a paper by D. A. Vogan, "The unitary dual of GL(n) over an archimedean field.", but (without having read the paper) it seems a bit abstract and does not treat the Plancherel formula.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I will need to think about this quite a bit.  The problem is not with the unitary dual of $\textrm{GL}(2)$; the problem is with the action of the central torus on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by dilations.  Believe it or not, this makes quite the difference both for the inversion and the behavior of matrix coefficients; in particular, the proof of exponential decay given in Howe-Tan for $\textrm{SL}$ does not carry over.  It is still true, but I will have to work it out or find another reference.

Comment: I don't think I have the time to answer before Tuesday, so if nobody answers, don't give up.

Comment: No problem, thanks so much for taking the time!

Comment: I haven't given up yet, but... Two days left for the bounty!

Comment: I am in the process of a revision for a paper, so I do not have time these days. I will answer, irrespective of the bounty deadline

Comment: Ok thanks! Then there's no rush

Comment: Let me briefly explain why it is taking me so long to reply: an answer really needs a lot of work that involves some very tricky computations.  Your group is not unimodular, so it does not have a Plancherel formula in the strictest sense: the Fourier transform is not unitary!  In order to compute the Plancherel measure, one needs to construct a series of (generally unbounded!) operators that compensate for this lack of unitarity, AND find a compatible classical Plancherel measure, none of which has been explicitly done for this group to my knowledge.

Comment: Parts of question 1 (describing the IURs) is very easy using the Mackey machine, but the Plancherel formula is the hardest question.  Part 2 has a positive answer; after all, you can decompose the Haar measure on your group pretty easily and achieve tractable integral representations by using Weyl's formulas and expansions in Euclidean space for the $\mathbb{R}^2$ part.  If you wish to start reading something until I can find enough time to do all the computations, the essential text is Folland's 'A course in abstract harmonic analysis'.  Everything I said above is detailed there.

Comment: I'm really amazed by the hard work you're putting in. Thanks again. I will start reading Folland.